# Change shortcuts in Acrobat 8

Tags: adobe-reader

How do I change and manage shortcuts inside of Acrobat 8? (This is the full version *not* reader)

I know with other Adobe Programs you can do this yet I cannot find a way in Acrobat. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more research and asking a few other places I discovered that it is not possible to edit shortcuts in Acrobat 8. A real shame I must say because it is a very handy feature in Photoshop =>